# CSS box width alternating in alternating rows

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply one of two different width values (either 70% or 30%) to the first or second box in a row.

- In the first row I want the first box to be 70% and the second box to be 30% width.
- In the next row I want the opposite.
- Then the next row should mimic the first row.
- These boxes are floated `<li>` elements.

I'm sure there's a way to do this with `nth-child` somehow...

I'd like to accomplish this **via CSS**. Here is a mockup of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough, you want the 1st and 4th box of every 4th box to be 70% wide, and the 2nd and 3rd of every 4th box to be 30% wide.

```css
div>div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #fff
}

div>div:nth-child(4n+1),
div>div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```